# How to inspect raw COM definitions in a TLB file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, com

An existing unmanaged C++ project uses a COM component declared and implemented in C#, and my header looks a bit like this:

```
#import "MyComponents.tlb" no_namespace named_guids

IComponentXYZ *pComponent;
```

Sometimes when I right-click on `IComponentXYZ` in the .h file and "Go to declaration", a `MyComponent.tlh` file is displayed which shows me the COM wrapper definitions. But other times, it says no definition exists.

Can I manually open this file in Visual Studio? I think it's being auto-generated. And while the Object Browser window lets me inspect TLB contents, it doesn't display the raw COM method declarations.

Comment: You may be looking for [OLE/COM Object Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx). Do `File > View TypeLib`, open your .tlb file. The tool decompiles back to IDL, essentially.

Comment: Worked for me. And don't forget to look in the Wow6432Node under HKLM\SOFTWARE when you're searching for CLSIDs.

Comment: [This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/64aa964d-4a18-4de6-9808-196c4a874fb4/comole-object-viewer?forum=vcgeneral) will get you further now. Essentially, install the Windows SDK to get OLE/COM Object Viewer.

Answer (score 2):

I also used OLEView twenty years ago. 
Some other good tool for looking inside a TLB and much more is:

**COMView**

- http://comview.allapp.biz/
- https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/COMView.shtml

Very helpful...